# maximize a form in it's load

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm developping an application using java and netbeans.

I have a form which I want to be maximized when I open it.

I googled about it and I foudn this code :

```
PersonelForm personelMainForm = new PersonelForm();
personelMainForm.setExtendedState(
   personelMainForm.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
personelMainForm.setVisible(true);
```

but it won't work for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what  you asking ?

Answer (score 1):

"It won't work for me" is a too vague statement...

I make a guess that since you are using Netbeans, your constructor calls the initComponents method. Add the two lines you googled like this and that should work:

```
public class PersonnelMainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public PersonnelMainForm() {
        initComponents();

        setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

You can also move these method calls to any other class however, then you can run it like here, leaving the constructor of PersonelMainForm with just the initComponents() call line:

```
...
PersonnelMainForm personnelMainForm=new PersonnelMainForm();
personnelMainForm.setExtendedState(personnelMainForm.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
personnelMainForm.setVisible(true);
...
```

Comment: MAXIMIZED_BOTH belongs to Frame the parent of JFrame. It may also be omitted.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH would also work. I try to avoid using non Swing components and variables...